# SP2013 : Display templates, SP.ClientContext(), Object doesn't support this action

Tags: 2013, display-template

I am building an display template. In the item template I have an onclick function on each item (picture). In this function I have some SharePoint Client Side code. The first row code is:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
```

In edit mode of my page it is working. When I publish the page I got this error:

Object doesn't support this action

I have googled and found these 2 solutions:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(updateProjectEC(), "sp.js");
```

or

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', updateProjectEC());
```

But how can I implement these solutions in my onclick event on each item. See the function "SetDetailInfo":

```
<div id="ItemAgenda">
<!--#_

var itemDate =  $getItemValue(ctx, "Created");
var itemBestuurderID =  $getItemValue(ctx, "Category");
itemBestuurderID.overrideValueRenderer($contentLineText);
var introText = $getItemValue(ctx, "IntroText");
introText.overrideValueRenderer($contentLineText);

var encodedId = $htmlEncode(ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId() + "_introTextId_");
var introTextId = encodedId + "introText";

_#-->
<img id="imgBestuurderFoto"  src="_#=itemDate=#_" width="200" height="200" onclick="SetDetailInfo('_#= itemBestuurderID =#_')" style="padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;border:0 !important;" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer my self. Add this registration in the masterpage:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink21" Name="sp.js" runat="server" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
```